# How to extract "sub-domain name" from a url presence in a long text containing multiple url

Tags: php

I have a long long text contains multiple url.   **BUT** there is **only one** url which is of blogspot.com    . That url will be like http://xxxxx.blogspot.com . How could i get the value of xxxx and store in a variable.

So if I have the whole text store in **$foo**. Can any one write the code to extract the subdomain out.

I guess it should be of only 1 or 2 line using **preg_match** . But i'am not getting it to work. Rejex are confusing me.

Thank you

Comment: write the code for you? heh... You should put into it at least a SMALL effort and then someone might help

Comment: Rather than `preg_match()` start with `parse_url()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and `explode()` the domain part on the dots, then extract the first from the resultant array.

Comment: @zoltan : sorry that i didn't put the code up there.. I did put effort googled, tried. but its just that i didn't put my messed up code up there. **ok any way next time i put some code to show my effort** Thanks You :) and thanks Michael for parse_url suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$foo = 'http://xxxxx.blogspot.com';
preg_match( '%http://(\w+).blogspot.com%', $foo, $matches);
var_dump( $matches[1]);
```

This will print `string(5) "xxxxx"`

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ExNrid)

Comment: Only problem I can see with thing is that `\w` doesn't match dashes, which are valid in domain names, and does match underscores, which are not.